# lamellar field if line intergral zero

Tags: vector-fields

I'm reading in the textbook [Electromagnetics with Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072899697) and it says (page 18) that if the line integral around a closed path is zero, $$\oint_C\vec{F}.d\vec{L}=0$$
then the vector field $\vec{F}$ is lamellar (conservative).  Specifically, the book says, "*Any field for which the line integral around a closed path is zero is called a **conservative** or **lamellar** **field***."

I read [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field) page and it makes sense.  Here is my question:  Is the above quote strictly correct (specifically for physical systems like electromagnetic fields)?  In other words, is it possible to find a path such that a line integral is **zero** for a field that is **not** a conservative field?

Just trying to get this locked down.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a path integral of the form:

$$\oint_C\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{L}$$

Letting $\vec{F}=\langle P(x,y),Q(x,y) \rangle$, we can rewrite as follows:
$$\oint_C Pdx +Qdy$$
We can then invoke green's theorem:

$$\oint_C Pdx +Qdy=\iint_R\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}dA$$

As you can see if the vector field is conservative, that is if $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ the integral is clearly zero. However we want to know if there exists a vector field that is not conservative, where the above integral is zero. Define a function:

$$f(x,y)=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$$
And then plug that into the integral and set it equal zero:
$$\iint_Rf(x,y)dA=0$$
If we let $f(x,y)=x^3y^2$ and the region $R$ be a square of side length 2 centered at the origin it is clear that this integral goes to zero. But can we write that function in terms of the partial derivatives? Yes, say we let our $Q$ and $P$ functions equal the following:
$$P(x,y)=x$$
$$\frac{\partial P}{y}=0$$
$$Q(x,y)=\frac{x^4y^2}{4}$$
$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial X}=x^3y^2$$
Therefore we have found a vector field $\vec{F}=\langle x,\frac{x^4y^2}{4} \rangle $ that is not conservative, which can yield a closed path integral equal to $0$.

Comment: That is outstanding. Do you know of any physical systems that would work this way too? e.g. electromagnetic fields or any other physical system

Comment: I'm a physics major, and no, not at all.

Comment: Thank you.  So for a real physical field we can positively say the field is conservative if line integral around closed path (any) is zero?

Comment: I hesitate to say yes, but I have not come across any.

Comment: The condition for a field to be conservative is that the integral around *any* closed loop vanishes. It is not sufficient to say that *some* integral vanishes.

Comment: Yea i know, but that's not what OP was asking. He asked, and I quote: " is it possible to find a path such that a line integral is zero for a field that is not a conservative field?" and I found a field that satisfies this result.